# JSON ListView and Clickable

Tags: android, json, listview, android-intent

I have been beating my head against the wall trying to get a dynamic clickable button to open either a new intent/fragment based upon the ListView item that is selected. I have been failing, badly :-).

I have the intent opening, but it is returning a null value which probably means that I am not opening up the intent that would be associated with the actual ListView item. Could someone please point me to where I am going wrong?

****EDIT****

As no one has helped me on this, I will rephrase it. Essentially, I am using the Volley class with ListView which are parsed from a webserver (json). From there, I am trying to establish that when the user clicks on the entry in the ListView that comes up, it opens its own unique screen. I am trying to get around using 1,000 intents, so I thought of parsing a portion of the lookup to the new intent which will then query the json database for a match. Is this an efficient way of doing this?

If not, is there is a better way?

If this is the best way (which I doubt), I have a bit of code below which I am having problems with:

Music Frag:

```
Song clickedObject = (Song)adapter.getItem(position);
     Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), songIntent.class);
     intent.putExtra("passTitle", clickedObject.getTitle());
     Log.e(clickedObject.getTitle(), "Passing: ");
     startActivity(intent);
```

The intent opens fine and it looks like the value is passed, but the loop is what I am having problems with is when I am trying to compare the String to what is a json lookup value:

Intent

```
for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
         try {
              JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
              Song song = new Song();
              song.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
              Song parseTitle = new Song();
              parseTitle.getTitle(jsonObject);
```

Sadly, I get no further as I can't compare the String object to what is in the 'song.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));' portion of the code. Can anyone help?

Many thanks

Comment: welcome to SO. Please add only the relevant part of code, it´s hard for everybody to read through all your stuff.

Comment: please add full code of that for loop

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort out an answer for this. I passed the click value to the intent and ran a variation of the Volley method (JsonArrayRequest) to loop through the JSON text file that I had. I compared this value with the one passed over and it is working.

Probably not the best solution, but considering that no one has offered much advise, I am going with this for now.